# Maximum |E| on a given degree-diameter -- Reference request

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given $d$, $k$ and $n$ of a graph G where

$n$: the number of vertices in G,

$d$: the maximum vertex-degree in G,

$n$: the exact diameter of G,

what is maximum possible $|E|$ ? That is, what is the maximum number of edges in a graph that has the values $(d, k, n)$ as given ?

I am looking for ***references*** to this solution in literature.

Note that this is different than the degree-diameter problem -- the problem of finding maximum $|V|$ on given $(d,k)$ which is bounded by Moore's value.

Also note: I am aware of the "minimum", rather than "maximum $|E|$" version of this problem which has solutions for $k=2$ and $k=3$ in literature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of any references, sorry, but my gut feeling would be that the graph giving the maximal $|E|$ would be made up from a subgraph of complete graphs strung out in a path... If you take $t$ copies of $K_{d+1}$ and remove an edge from each, and then join the copies via the vertices which had the edge removed then you will get a graph with maximum degree $d$, diameter $2t-1$ and $td(d+1)/2-1$ edges. You can then delete some of the $td$ vertices until you have $n$ left.

Comment: @jp26 Thank you for the input. However, I need the reference to cite.

Comment: Why do you believe such a reference exists? There are many unknown results about diameter...

Comment: probably not worked. but it doesn't seem as hard as the lower bound which is solved in part.